# LinearLayout with ListLayout inside ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I want complete screen scroll-able except ads. But that list view shows one item if height is fill-content or wrap content. Only list view scroll in that scenario.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/playback_error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/error_message_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/error_vertical_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/error_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/error_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/error_vertical_padding"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Connectivity error!" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/verve_sdk_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="The Best Music"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryDesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="test description" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textlines"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Episodes / Tracks"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    tools:background="#272727"
                    tools:text="Episodes / Tracks" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
                <!--app:layout_collapseMode="pin"-->
                <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"-->
                <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>-->
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried fill-content/wrap content, but nothing working.

I have more than 50 item in list view but i want to scroll screen with linear layout also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rorkom.nikhil.scrolltest.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">
            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:text="The Best Music"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/somedesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="John Doe, his brothers, his sisters, his pets and his more than amazing band" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Add"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks NikHil, but in scrollview android:layout_above="@id/list_view" - line giving an error, that list_view is not a sibling for same relativelayout

Comment: Its same as previous layout display, just scrolling list view at a one item each scroll. Not scrolling complete screen except ads

Comment: ` <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >` -- Its also not working if i used nestedscroll instead of scrollview

Comment: Listview will automatically contain scrollbar. This might be the reason for it considering as nested scroll view

Comment: But what if i want scroll view with complete page which include linear layout and list layout

Comment: You can use scrolling activity template provided by the android studio for the nested scroll view

Comment: Are you still looking for the same?

Comment: Yes, i am still stuck in this situation

Comment: I changed my answer. It works for me. Please check it

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, i just added my layout in top comment. Its working. But if i scroll list view along, list view scroll itself also. And i want ads sticky , should not scroll.  And i don't know about com.rorkom.nikhil.scrolltest.ScrollingActivity and @style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay, because i am very new. I used other.

Comment: I had edited it again. You can place your add in place of the textview

Comment: Please check top most code, i changed my layout with top one which i  just edited. Its working good, But one problem is that when we move all list to top than i can not see again to linear layout. I can not scroll down further except list layout.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, but my list view also scrolling itself. Any suggestion